# mongoose. Как найти объект по полю в объекте?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Я использую следующую схему mongoDb

```
conn.model('feed', new mongoose.Schema({
 'feed': Object,
 'id': String,
 'object': String }));
```

Как мне с изпользуя  M.findOne(?) найти объект по полю которое находится в  feed: Object ?
Я думал должно так работать

```
        M.findOne({ feed:{ name:"Jon" }})
             .exec()
             .then(news => {
              out(news)
              })
```

но так поиск выдаёт null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
await M.find({ "auth.name": "chef" })
```

Comment: Возможно, ответ правильный, но, пожалуйста, поясните его. Для того, чтобы внести улучшающую правку, Вы можете воспользоваться кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1006602/edit). В будущем, пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более осмысленные ответы. — [из очереди проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/386493)

Comment: Ответ правильный. Для себя ведь пишу. А подсказали мне его здесь.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57199738/how-to-find-object-property-in-mongoose?noredirect=1#comment100908237_57199738

Я особо не знаю что на это ответить, потому что не знаю, с чем связанно различие в синтаксисе между java script и mongo. У них парсер немного по другому видимо написан.